# Running a Shell-script on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and getting a Toast Notification on another VM

Tags: powershell, server, virtual-machine, toast, restart

So im writing a Shell-script that runs on a Windows Server 2012 R2. The script is restarting all vm's in the Network at a specific time. Now i want to add a ToastNotification for the VM-Users that the vm will restart in a few seconds. This is what i have at the moment.

```
while ($null -ne $Global:vmName[$Global:counter] ){
    $vm = $Global:vmName[$Global:counter]
    Write-host "VMname $($vm)"
    
    if("$($vm)"-eq "VM-XYZ" ) {
        Write-Host "Found XYZ"
        
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        $global:balmsg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        $path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
        $balmsg.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
        $balmsg.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Warning
        $balmsg.BalloonTipText = "Die VM startet in 30 Sekunden neu"
        $balmsg.BalloonTipTitle = "Achtung!"
        $balmsg.Visible = $true
        $balmsg.ShowBalloonTip(1)
    }
    $Global:counter++; 
}
```

The thing i imagine should something be like this:

```
while ($null -ne $Global:vmName[$Global:counter] ){
    $vm = $Global:vmName[$Global:counter]
    Write-host "VMname $($vm)"

    if("$($vm)"-eq "VM-XYZ" ) {
        Write-Host "Found XYZ"

        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        $global:balmsg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        $path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
        $balmsg.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
        $balmsg.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Warning
        $balmsg.BalloonTipText = "Die VM startet in 30 Sekunden neu"
        $balmsg.BalloonTipTitle = "Achtung!"
        $balmsg.Visible = $true

        **$vm.ShowBalloontip(1) 
        $vm.$balmsg.ShowBalloonTip(1)**
    }
    $Global:counter++; 
}
```

I appreciate every help i can get im stuck on this for a few hours now. And i couldn't find any answers in the internet for that specific problem.

Comment: So, first we have to play spot-the-difference between your two code samples, then we need to guess what "that specific problem" actually is. Please help us help you. Add specific details to your question, make clear what you've changed between the code samples, etc.

Comment: The only difference is that i placed the $vm infront of it. That means that the VM should show the Notification and not the Server.
So the script runs on the Server and iterates through all VM's. Then the script should create a Toastnotification that is exactly the same for every VM. And in those VM's the ToastNotification should appear so that the user of the VM sees that his VM will restart in like 30 seconds.
So to sum everthing up i cant get it to work that the ToastNotification is displayed in the VM's.